# ESXi graphics passthrough not toggleable

Tags: esxi

I am attempting to configure a new ESXi 6.7 host for passthrough graphics. On the IT provided host the GPU is available for passthrough. This is a 10 year old server repurposed for ESXi and not doing the job very well.
I have repurposed a (less old) Lenovo desktop with an nVidia Quadro M4000 card that I want to use for passthrough. But ALL the hardware is greyed out, and the Toggle passthrough button never activates. Is this a drivers issue, or is there a config I need to do somewhere to globally enable passthrough as an option? Or is it perhaps because there is only one card so I need to configure for headless operation first?

Comment: The requirements for GPU passthrough are pretty specific, if the option is grayed out, then it likely is indeed a driver issue.

Comment: @ramhound does the fact that EVERYTHING is greyed out suggest I need to look for drivers for more than just the GPU? And, which drivers do I download. I have seen other posts talking about this card working, but at least in nVidia's downloads I don't see an ESXi option. Can I use the Linux 64-bit drivers?

Comment: I have an ESXi 6.7 host and what likely is a equivalent era GPU, and i personally, have never been able to assigned dedicated VRAM to my VM infrastructure. However, VT-d or the AMD equivalent is CPU restricted, so that might be one problem you have.  In my host I have Xeon CPUs from the applicable era as the GPU which support VT-d.  GPU passthrough is a very complicated issue when dealing with legacy Nvidia hardware, only the enterprise hardware during the legacy era (i.e. the hardware no longer supported), actually supported GPU passthrough.  I would need more information.

Comment: @ramhound so an AMD GPU may or may not support passthrough depending on CPU? Ugh, so much complication. It's got a Xeon E5 v4, so maybe I can find a decent AMD card that will work. It would be nice to get passthrough working, but in the end just improving on what the IT clowns provided will be a big help.

Comment: I have not research AMD's version of VT-d in months.